# ElastiCache backup consistency

Tags: amazon-elasticache

Is ElastiCache Redis backup a snapshot of the cache content at a certain point in time and contains all updates which happened before this point and no updates after it?

My goal is to understand if the following scenario, which can potentially lead to inconsistency in our system, is possible.
Assume the cache contains two keys, X and Y, and both of them are 0 at some moment. Then X is changed to 1, after which Y is changed to 1 (in this order). Simultaneously with these updates, a backup is running. Can it happen that the backup contains X=0 and Y=1?

Answer (score 1):

ElastiCache redis backup, provides a point in time snapshot, which means that if the snapshot is created successfully, there shouldn't be an any data inconsistency issues (e.g., X < Y as described above).
This topic is covered with details in AWS documentations:

- [Backup and restore for ElastiCache for Redis](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html)
- [How synchronization and backup are implemented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Replication.Redis.Versions.html)

With that in mind, while single instance of Redis is always consistent, if the snapshot is created on a replica, then we should consider again the answer to this question.